# Angular $http.get not passing parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, spotify

This seems like a simple problem, and I must be overlooking something small.

I have a function that accesses Spotify API and searches for an artist. I know that accessing this route via a normal URL returns a result. (e.g. `http://localhost:3001/search?artist=%27Linkin%20Park%27`) Here the code that does that:

```
router.get('/search', function(req, res, next)
{
    var artist = req.param('artist');
    console.log("Artist: " + artist);
    smartSpot.getArtistID(artist, function(data)
    {
        console.log("Data: " + data);
        res.json(data.id);
    });
});
```

Then, there is the code on the front end to search for the artist. This is all done via angular.

```
angular.module('smart-spot', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$http',
        function($scope, $http)
        {
            $scope.createPlaylist = function()
            {
                var artist = $scope.artist;
                console.log(artist);
                window.open("/login", "Playlist Creation", 'WIDTH=400, HEIGHT=500');
                return $http.get('/search?=' + $scope.artist) //this doesn't pass in the artist
                    .success(function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                    });

            }
        }
    ]);
```

The `$http.get()` does not pass in the $scope.artist` value properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you might be missing the "artist" query param in your string concatenation.

```
$http.get('/search?artist=' + $scope.artist)
```

Alternatively, you could pass the artist as a query param.

```
function createPlaylist() {
    return $http.get('/search', { params : { artist : $scope.artist } })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response;
    }, function(error) {
        return $q.reject(error);
    });
}
```

Also, I would avoid using .success.  I believe that's depreciated in favor of the syntax above.  First param is success function, second is fail function.

Comment: Oh. Duh. Yup. I knew it was something simple. Thanks so much! We couldn't figure out why this was not working.

Comment: $q is an angular's service for managing promises. If you wanted to do something after the call to $scope.createPlaylist, you would want to return $q.reject() from the error function.  That's how you create a "promise chain".  So then you can call $scope.createPlaylist().then(function(response) {}, function(error) {}).  So if createPlaylist succeeds, the next succeed function in the chain is run.  If createPlaylists fails, then the next fail function in the chain is run.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

you can pass parameters via

```
$http.get('/search', {
    params: {
        artist: $scope.artist
    }
})
.success(function(data)
{
console.log(data);
});
```